# Nginx Reverse proxy with no DNS for multiple websites

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I have two websites on a single `ubuntu 16` server and I want to make them accessible by network using `nginx` `reverse proxy` and `gunicorn` (Gunicorn internally serves websites on `127.0.0.1:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8001`).

Both Websites will **never** have `DNS` pointing to my server and both **must** be running under port `80`. So question is, how can I set reverse proxy for these sites? I am in situation where I cant catch hostname or different port in order to user to enter specific site.

**My first_website.conf:**

```
upstream first_website {
    server unix:/var/www/first_website/first_website_env/run/gunicorn.sock 
    fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    # normally I would use different host name
    # to check, which site user wants to retrieve.
    server_name 123.12.34.789;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning to differentiate the servers then? do you want them to have different entering points? for example `123.12.34.789/server1`?

Comment: Yes 123.12.34.789/server1 would be a good option. But I am not sure how to implement this, and if is this a good practice to do.

Answer (score 0):

an option would be to place the servers on different url locations for example:

```
upstream first_website {
    server unix:/var/www/first_website/first_website_env/run/gunicorn.sock 
    fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name 123.12.34.789;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /server1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }
    }

    location /server2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that does the trick for you.